# "Force-casting" a returned type

Tags: c#, types

This should be a pretty trivial one.

Can C# return a type that is "force-cast", that is where the following ***fails***:

```
 private ICollection<string> _strings = new List<string>();
 public IEnumerable<string> Strings
 {
     get
     {
          return ((IEnumerable<string>)_strings);
     }
 }

 /* I should not know that Strings can be cast to ICollection */
 public void AddToStrings()
 {
     ICollection<string> st = ((ICollection<string>)Strings); /* I should fail */
     st.Add("MyString");
 }
```

I'm aware I could do this:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Strings
 {
     get
     {
          return ((IEnumerable<string>)_strings.ToArray());
     }
 }
```

But this seems (1) unnecessary, (2) still doesn't stop them casting to an ICollection, just from adding and (3) I'm just plain curious about the general question.

#### Clarification

Some people seem unsure about what I am trying to achieve here. I am trying to prevent outside classes from violating the contract I provide them. I have not said that Strings is an ICollection - it just so happens that I am using that internally - and as such no outside class should be able to treat my returned variable as an ICollection. I don't want to expose modification behaviour to them, and I don't want them to treat my variable as an ICollection in case I later change the way I generate that IEnumerable.

More generally, can I return an object as an instance of one of its more specific types,  and prevent later casting to one of its more general types. For example, while you can yield a new IEnumerable, could you return an IDisposable object that cannot be cast back to whatever type it was (i.e. only has Dispose() and object methods callable)?

Comment: What exactly fails? What errors messages?

Comment: how is that related to boxing ? and why should it fail ? `ICollection<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`... Ultimately, what are you REALLY trying to do ?

Comment: It doesn't fail, that's the problem. Outside classes should not be able to treat an IEnumerable I give them as an ICollection just because my internal class happens to use that.

Comment: Arrays implement `ICollection<T>`, so your last piece of code wouldn't do what you want either (although the call to Add would fail)

Comment: As I understand it, he doesn't want the user of the `Strings` method to use any methods on the returned object other than those defined by `IEnumerable`. In particular he doesn't want them to cast it to ICollection because the fact that it is an ICollection is an implementation detail that the user should not rely on (also using mutating methods such as Add might cause unwanted behavior).

Comment: @sepp2k Exactly, and while you can in this case yield a new IEnumerable, that doesn't apply generally. What if I wanted to return a IDisposable object for instance so that you can only call Dispose() and Object methods?

Comment: @Graphain: I tried to answer the more general question here - though Thomas was exactly right for this specific example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah ok, I see what you mean now...

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Strings
 {
     get
     {
          foreach (var s in _strings) yield return s;
     }
 }
```

But it has nothing to do with boxing...

Comment: Thanks, this is an example of the .ToArray() pattern I mention, but as you've said it doesn't allow me to box a type in, and prevent auto unboxing later, instead I'm just generating a new type for them. I can't say "this variable I give you is just an object". What if it wasn't an IEnumerable I wanted to return, but instead just an object with ONLY the methods available to the object class?

Comment: I think you really need to lookup the definition of [boxing and unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)...

Comment: There's no way to do that AFAIK

Comment: "Boxing is the process of converting a value type  to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type." I want to *box* my ICollection to an IEnumerable, and prevent later *unboxing* to ICollection.

Comment: Your use of the term 'boxing' is causing confusion, I think, since it means something very specific (copying a value type to the heap and returning a reference) in .Net. Are what you trying to accomplish is just removing the ability to cast to the internal collection? If so, the above works, since it returns a new instance of a compiler generated type, not the internal collection.

Comment: Fair enough I'll rephrase without 'boxing'. I was taught it from the general "what/why" language perspective instead of the "how" technical perspective.

Answer (score 5):

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125030/pre-boxing-a-returned-type/3125041#3125041) provided you the correct answer, for this specific instance.

That being said, there is no "general purpose" way to prevent users from attempting to cast types to their "actual" type instead of an interface you provide them.

The closest thing you can do is use types that are internal within your assembly, and not visible to the caller.  This will prevent the user from being able to use your type directly (at least without resorting to reflection in elevated trust situations).

However, in general, I would suggest not worrying about this.  Any user who casts your type to an undocumented, internal implementation detail's type is just asking for trouble, and I would not try to code a way of preventing this.  Doing so is just doing yourself a disservice, since you're making your code less maintainable.

Comment: Thanks Reed, this is a difficult one to call because this answer actually answers my question but Thomas' provides a solution to the particular example. It is a pity that you have to create a new instance (which is sometimes impossible) to limit this behaviour. It means I can never expose modifiable member variables even as their non-modifiable interface types.

Comment: @Graphain: Well, if you use internal types, it's pretty safe.  With reflection, all bets are off, though.  That being said, I really would say "just don't worry about this" (unless you're doing something that's high-security related, etc)

Comment: I kind of worry about other coders within the same assembly interacting with my class incorrectly :P Reflection is a non-issue (if they're going to use reflection then they can access private variables etc. anyway).

Comment: @Graphain: If it's coders working inside the same assembly that are worrying you, you have more pressing concerns...

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case where you return an IEnumerable Thomas's solution using yield is probably the best. In the general case where the returned interface might be anything (like IDisposable as you mentioned in your edit) the only way to achieve what you want would be to create a wrapper class that implements the given interface using delegation (e.g. a class MyDisposable that holds an `IDisposable` and implements the Dispose method by calling Dispose on the IDisposable it holds).

Comment: And in that case I would have to instantiate an instance of that wrapper class each return too. Thanks though, this is probably the best approach more generally.

Comment: Should mention, this wrapper class should include an implicit operator to the type it wraps (e.g. implicit IDispoable operator).